# JS изменить текст на другой вкладке

Tags: javascript, jquery

Допустим открыта страница в браузере *mysite.com/page-1.php* в которой есть элемент:

```
<span id="test-1"></span>
```

Далее в новой я открываю страницу *mysite.com/page-2.php* в которой есть **js** команда которая должна сменить текст в элементе `test-1` в первой вкладке - *mysite.com/page-1.php*.

Возможно ли как то выполнить данную задачу средствами **js/jquery**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предложенный вариант с `storage` работает только на одной и той де странице, то есть если открыть в нескольких табах `page-1.php` то предложенный вариант с `window.addEventListener('storage', e => console.info('Changed'))` сработает, иначе предлагаю сделать след. образом, как из ответа https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/729727/243667

page-1.php

```
var storageParam = "name";
var defaultStorageVal = localStorage.getItem(storageParam);
setInterval(function() {
    var val = localStorage.getItem(storageParam);
    if (val != defaultStorageVal) {
        document.getElementById("test-1").innerHTML=val;
        defaultStorageVal = val;
        // если alert один раз только должен сработать, убейте интервал
    }
}, 500); // тут уже сами смотрите
```

page-2.php

```
localStorage.setItem("name", "text")
```

Comment: Скопировал в точности код как на приведенном примере, не срабатывает хоть убейся(... может я что то не так делаю? кроме кода который нужно повесить на page-1.php и page-2.php может быть еще какой то код нужно подключать?

Comment: Нашел причину, page-1.php загружалась по https, a page-2.php http, при загрузке page-2 по https событие сработало.

Comment: если помог ответ, отметь, пожалуйста его верным

Answer (score 4):

Используйте событие [`storage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Events/storage):

*Page 1:*

```
window.addEventListener('storage', e => console.info('Changed'))
```

*Page 2:*

```
localStorage.setItem('name', 42)
```

---

При изменении хранилища, на всех вкладаках с этим хранилищем произойдёт событие, где можно проверить имя и изменить текст.

**Важно:**
Обратите внимание на то, что изменение (и, соответственно, событие) произойдёт только при... изменении данных.
Т. е. если в `name` уже лежало значение `42`, то установка `name = 42` **не** приведёт к генерации события.

Comment: Не получается сделать, не могли бы вы показать на примере как сделать добавление какого текста в элемент <span id="test-1"></span> этим способом?

Comment: Что не получается?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/729621/js-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B5