# JS событие на другой вкладке

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Открываю страницу `mysite.com/1.php` в браузере со следующим кодом:

```
window.addEventListener('storage', function(e) { alert(1); } )
```

Далее открываю в новой вкладу вторую страницу `mysite.com/2.php` со следующим кодом:

```
localStorage.setItem('name', 42);
```

По задумке нужно что бы открытии `mysite.com/2.php` на странице `mysite.com/1.php` сработал алерт, но он не срабатывает.
Раньше никогда не работал с `storage`.
Подскажите что не так, если можно, приведите рабочий пример.

Comment: Не воспроизводится в хроме, лисе.

Comment: Есть еще какой то способ вызвать событие в первой вкладке из второй вкладки что бы наверняка работал в всех браузерах?

Comment: Какой браузер Вы используете?

Comment: Этот пример пробовал на хроме и опере, не работает ни там ни там.

Comment: @Other, скорее всего, проблема не в событии, а в значении. Я уже ответ написал.

Comment: @Qwertiy, возможно, но в ссылке, которую я приложил, чётко написано что " has been modified".

Comment: @Other, не вижу от тебя никаких ссылок.

Comment: @Qwertiy, этот вопрос лишь порождение [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/729587/207618).

Comment: @Other, по твоей ссылке: "Событие storage сигнализирует,  что данные ... были изменены" - если там уже 42 и ты снова пишешь 42, то ничего не меняется и событие не возникает. Я это проверил в хроме перед тем, как писать ответ.

Comment: @Qwertiy, не вижу противоречия. 1) В первый раз там нет 42. 2) Второй раз писать 42 - не будет изменения, это так, просто не думал что нужно уточнить: изменение - это изменение :)

Comment: @Other, если открыть вторую страницу раньше первой, то изменения, показывающего alert, никогда не будет.

Comment: @Qwertiy, согласен, можно сделать так, что не сработает. Но для этого и передаётся смысл и ссылка на ману, чтобы подумать и понять ИМХО.

Answer (score 1):

Событие срабатывает только при изменении. Т. е. когда ты впервые откроешь вторую страницу, если в этот момент открыта первая, то на ней выполнится подписчик и (при условии, что браузер не блокирует alert'ы с неактивных вкладок) сработает alert.

При последующих записях событие не выполнится, поскольку изменения значения не происходит - ты записываешь то, что там находится.

Если ты хочешь alert на каждое обновление страницы, замени свои `42` на `Math.ramdom()`.

Проверял в хроме на таком коде:

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '0.0.0.0';
const port = 3000;

http.createServer((req, res) => {
  var url = req.url.substr(1);
  var script = "";

  switch (url) {
    case '1':
      script = "window.addEventListener('storage', function(e) { alert(1); } )";
      break;

    case '2':
      script = "localStorage.setItem('name', Math.random());";
      break;

    default:
      res.writeHead(404);
      res.end();
  }

  res.writeHead(200, { 'content-type': 'text/html' });
  res.end(`<!doctype html>
    <title>Page #${url}</title>
    <script>${script}</script>
    <h1>${url}</h1>
  `);
}).listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

Скринвидео (41 секунда): https://cloud.mail.ru/public/Be2J/o5T7ZhHgU
Если скачать оригинал, то 1.03 MB, кодек h264.

Comment: Есть риск что не сработает, кто знает госпожу Случайность? :)

Comment: @Other, ну можно while прикрутить. Я в целом идею показал, что нужны разные значения. Можно инкрементить, но это только 2^53 раз сработает, а потом перестанет.

Comment: Почему столько?

Comment: @Other, `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` ну и `Math.pow(2,53) - 1`. Потому что только 53 значимых бита у double. А вот код для проверки: `for (var x=Math.pow(2,53)-4, q=0; q<8; ++q, ++x) console.log(x)`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvpJx.png

Comment: Пробую пример в хроме, на второй странице вместо 42 поставил Math.random(). все одно не работает, выше описаний код не срабатывает так как есть какая то ошибка http://joxi.ru/EA44BXVTDKazjA не могу увидеть где

Comment: @Юрий, это код сервера на nodejs, его не нада на страницу совать.

Comment: @Юрий, попробуй заменить `alert` на `document.write` - тогда всё содержимое страницы будет заменяться тем, что выводишь.

Comment: Сделал вот так на первой страницу window.addEventListener('storage', function(e) { document.write('666'); } ) на вторую localStorage.setItem('name', Math.random()); не работает document.write.

Я в js не силен, вы уж извините за глупые вопросы, но что бы работало  нужно еще какой то код добавлять что сработало событие?

Comment: @Юрий, без обид: изучите сначала основы, хотя бы понимать будете что и куда работает. А разжёвывать постоянно - не вариант, как минимум всех возможных глюков не знаем.

Comment: @Юрий, могу видео записать, что у меня работает.

Comment: @Qwertiy. так, можно подробнее? Почему безопасное (что за опасность?), почему инкремент не работает, а `+1` - легко?

Comment: Qwertiy, если не сложно запишите буду признательным за видео.

Comment: @Юрий, держи видео.

Comment: @Qwertiy Безопасно инкрементить можно как-то так `i = ++i & 0xFF`

Comment: @ReklatsMasters, ага. Можно даже `i = ~~(i+1)`. Или вообще вместо инкремента делать `i^=1`.

Answer (score 1):

Логично, что `window.addEventListener` просматривает событие в пределах одного окна/таба, а по работе с storage, я так понимаю страница должна быть одна и та же, то есть если открыть две одинаковые страницы, то предложенный вариант с `window.addEventListener` будет работать. А если без `window.addEventListener` можно реализовать след. образом:

1.php

```
var storageParam = "name";
var defaultStorageVal = localStorage.getItem(storageParam);
setInterval(function() {
    var val = localStorage.getItem(storageParam);
    if (val != defaultStorageVal) {
        alert(1);
        defaultStorageVal = val;
        // если alert один раз только должен сработать, убейте интервал
    }
}, 500); // тут уже сами смотрите
```

Если в 2.php выполнить код ниже, то на 1.php выполнится alert

```
localStorage.setItem("name", 12);
```