# Чтение данные из другой вкладки браузера

Tags: javascript

Мне надо прочитать значение data-атрибута на одной вкладке браузера и вывести на другой. Возможно ли такое на JS?

```
<div class="photo">
            <a href="#">
              <img src="img/women/model.jpg" alt="">
              <h3 class="photo__name">Rita Bahmurdinova</h3>
              <div class="about">
                <span>Height: 150</span><br>
                <span>Bust: 150</span><br>
                <span>Waist: 150</span><br>
                <span>Hips: 150</span><br>
                <span>Shoes: 150</span><br>
                <span>Hair: 150</span><br>
                <span>Eyes: 150</span>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
```

Comment: `Eyes: 150` - убило. А если по  делу, то о каких "страницах" идет речь? О разных вкладках в браузере?

Comment: ))) да, о  разных вкладках .

Comment: данный случай никак. т.к. новое окно - новый запуск скриптов.

Comment: Можно попробовать [через хранилище](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/729587/207618). Прочёл на одной вкладке, дёрнул хранилище, на другой делаешь что надо.

Comment: @n.osennij на самом деле можно, тут уже 1000 раз обсуждали. Можно и через сервер, можно и с помощью local storage. Автору, кстати, советую о нем почитать.

Comment: Вот именно то, о чем @other написал.