# Как на javascript сделать функцию, исполняемую единовременно в одном экземпляре на сайте

Tags: javascript

Вот, собственно, и весь вопрос. Как в принципе сделать так, чтобы, вот если у меня пользователь откроет несколько вкладок моего сайта (причем могут быть разные страницы), чтобы у меня только на одной из них запустилась функция.

Для чего нужно: *я хочу создать объект EventSource лишь на одной вкладке с сайтом, при закрытии/обновлении этой "главной" вкладки - перекидывать "главность" на любую другую вкладку. Поток будет получать данные, если обновляются статистические счетчики, пихать в localStorage измененные данные, далее, на всех вкладках будут обновляться данные. В принципе, это не особо важно - просто написал, вдруг существует еще более дешевый и простой способ это сделать.*

Собсно вот... попробовал сделать, долго очень копался (может я просто не очень понимал, что именно нужно искать), но вот как-то получилось. Когда подгружается страница, считывается "специальная переменная" из localStorage - если вдруг там null, то значение localStorage перезаписывается на "555" (красивое число просто). Также при этом устанавливается, что при событии unload (только на "главной" вкладке) значение "специальной переменной" очистится, что вызовет на всех вкладках с моим сайтом mainStorageFunction - и какая-то из вкладок снова станет "главной".

Интересует меня:

1. нормальный ли это способ?
2. гарантирует ли это, что у будет всегда ровно одна "главная" вкладка (если вкладки с моим сайтом есть)?
3. в принципе реально может возникнуть ситуация, когда "главная" вкладка зависла или взорвалась и событие unload по какой-то причине не вызвалось. или оно вызовется в любом случае, даже если питание отключить?

P.S. нет, просто аяксом не хочу постоянно долбить сервер, это противоречит моей религии.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    mainStorageFunction();

    window.addEventListener('storage', function(e) {
        mainStorageFunction();
    });
});

function mainStorageFunction () {
    if (localStorage.getItem('now_stored') === null) {
        localStorage.setItem('now_stored', 555);
        window.addEventListener('unload', function () {
            localStorage.removeItem('now_stored');
        });
        document.getElementById('wai').innerHTML = 555;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('wai').innerHTML = 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="wai"></div>
```

Comment: А что будет если пользователь закроет главную вкладку, или даже что ещё хуже она зависнет?

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин, последовательно: сначала вызывается событие unload, по которому `localStorage.removeItem('now_stored');`, ну а так как произвелась манипуляция с localStorage, то вызывается следом `mainStorageFunction();` во всех остальных вкладках - какая-то из них "успевает", как бы это выразиться, "стать главной".

Comment: а если вкладка зависнет, или по какой-то другой причине unload не вызовется?

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин, неееет = ( тоже интересный вопрос, что можно в этом случае придумать.

Comment: Это тоже решаемо, можно постоянно проводить Check не существование главной вкладки... Но по-моему мнение обычный ajax на сервер возможно лучшее решение, и вообще непонятно зачем несколько вкладок нужно...

Comment: возможно нужно это: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/729587/191482

Comment: хотя смотрю  в вопросе есть.... тогда непонятно в чем проблема) надо наверное весь вопрос прочитать чтоли

Comment: Check может быть такой что главная вкладка постоянно в специальную localStorage переменную пишет текущее время. Например каждые 20 секунд. Другие вкладки могут проверять, если например за 40 секунд время не обновилось, значит вкладка умерла. Но это, хм... очень странно мягко говорят такая функциональность.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, эту часть я как раз сделал уже) но вот за инфу о том, что событие срабатывает только если значение реально "изменилось" - спс огромное. Вопрос собсно в том что че-то как-то страшно такую штуку запускать... локально-то я могу проверить - запустить 100 вкладок (больше, наверное, бедняжка хром не выдержит), а как оно будет на реальном сайте, где может 1к пользователей запустить каждый по 10 вкладок?

Comment: @АлександрБелинский обычно всё-таки у сайта постепенно растёт число пользователей, и баги проявляются через feedback пользователей. Думаю багов бояться смысла нету. Если будет глюк, пользователи напишут. А код писать надо красиво, что бы клюков было поменьше, и такие значения как 555 желательно в константы записывать...

Comment: Тем более на первом периоде можно анонсировать как бету версию, тогда не так страшно будет, и уже не будет претензий за недоконца работающий проект. Гугл Трансляции в бете были больше года, а может и сейчас ещё в них...

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин, вот с записью времени - хорошая идея, спасибо. Может кто-нибудь из вас всё-таки ответ оформит?) Я почему еще вопрос создал: я плохо разбираюсь в javascript, вдруг я в принципе что-то неправильно делаю и есть какое-то более простое и изящное решение. Или какое-нибудь более "гарантированное".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По сути браузеры и вкладки браузера не предполагают такой работы, а если бы предполагали то для этого был бы нормальный продуманный интерфейс, поэтому то что вы делаете это использование топора для завинчивание шурупов. С другой стороны если шуруп надо завинтить, а ничего кроме топора нету, то тогда и топор будет большим благо.

С учётом вышесказанного ваше решение нормально, заисключением того что необходимо продумать ситуацию при которой главная вкладка может зависнуть, умереть или быть закрыта без вызова unload.

Как решение это в некоторую localStorage переменную главной вкладкой каждые 15 секунд записывать текущее время. А другие вкладки проверяют это время, если разница в записи с текущим временем больше например чем 40 Секунд, значит главная вкладка умерла или зависла. Кроме того продумать ситуацию если старая главная вкладка отвиснет.

Может быть ситуация что сразу несколько вкладкок захотят стать главной после смерти старой главной. Тут можно просто первая которая захотела, ставит специальный флаг в localStorage, и другие уже проверяют установлен этот флаг или нет. Хотя 100% защиты это не даст, но вероятность двух главных табов будет невысока.

Answer (score 2):

Нс сколько кроссбраузерным должно быть решение?  Просто вполне возможно,  вам нужен service worker.  Он будет мастер-процессом, а все вкладки в этом случае будут слейвами,  так что не надо будет думать на тему того как переключать мастера.

Comment: Полезные ссылочки посоветуете какие-нибудь, где про это прочитать?

Comment: Ну я лично всё изучаю по документации или путём экспериментов.  Так что посоветовать могу только https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers

Comment: что-то не получается заставить serviceWorker-а поддерживать EventSource - он его создает и тут же обрубает (судя по всему, это связано со "временем жизни serviceWorker-а). Или нужно использовать не eventSource, а что-то другое?

Comment: Да, прошу прощения, кажется я затупил. ServiceWorker действительно является коротко-живущей сущностью. Есть другой вид воркеров - SharedWorker'ы - они как раз живут долго и умеют работать с нескольким окнами.
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/SharedWorker
И тут кстати кто-то очень похожу задачу решал аналогичным методом: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35837967/increase-service-worker-life-time